# Show image as finder into Mac OS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

How do i show `UIImageView` same as the image below on iPad (which i make screen shot of the finder into Mac OS).

Please help me make more clear about the question, because i don't know the name of this behaviour. User can swipe left right to view image.

[image]

Comment: You will need to build it yourself. With a `UIScrollView` and `UIImageView`.

Comment: Look for CoverFlow in CocoaControls for iOS: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=CoverFlow

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using UICollectionView with custom UICollectionViewLayout.

For example, look at this project:
[Coverflow Implementation using UICollectionView](https://github.com/singer1026/Coverflow)